# How to write frame back after image processing through OpenGL ES shader?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, shader

I want to perform kind of image processing through OpenGL ES shaders, for example, undistortion. The result needs to be stored back to image buffer instead of shown on screen.

For example, the function like

```
glesDewarp( const UINT8* image_in, UINT8* image_out);
```

According to my reading, now the process is

1. load image as a texture
2. perform image process by shader language
3. render buffer to an image

I wonder if I can pass kind of image address to the shader, that I can get the processed image directly without render to another image.

However, I checked the specification of fragment shader. It has only one changeable variable - gl_FragDepth. It can't be used for my purpose. And, in other discussions, somebody said due to the pipeline of shaders, it is impossible to access the data in shaders directly.

If so, is there any way that I could achieve a fast image process through OpenGL ES shader language? Could it be done by general calculation in shaders without using texture?

I attach my codes here if any helps. Thanks for your reading.

Step1 : load image as a texture

```
glGenTextures ( 1, g_hTextureHandle );
glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_hTextureHandle[0] );
glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexImage2D ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, nFormat, nWidth, nHeight, 0, nFormat, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pImageData );
```

Step2 : perform image undistortion by shader language

```
g_strVSProgram =
"#version 300 es                                                    \n"
"attribute vec4 g_vVertex;                                          \n"
"attribute vec4 g_vTexcoord;                                        \n"
"                                                                   \n"
"varying   vec4 g_vVSTexcoord;                                      \n"
"                                                                   \n"
"void main()                                                        \n"
"{                                                                  \n"
"    gl_Position  = g_vVertex;                                      \n"
"    g_vVSTexcoord = g_vTexcoord;                                   \n"
"}                                                                  \n";

g_strFSProgram =
"#version 300 es                                                    \n"
"#ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH                                  \n"
"   precision highp float;                                          \n"
"#else                                                              \n"
"   precision mediump float;                                        \n"
"#endif                                                             \n"
"                                                                   \n"
"uniform   sampler2D g_sImageTexture;                               \n"
"varying   vec4      g_vVSTexcoord;                                 \n"
"                                                                   \n"
"void main()                                                        \n"
"{                                                                  \n"
"    gl_FragColor = texture2D(g_sImageTexture, g_vVSTexcoord.xy);   \n"
"}                                                                  \n";
```

Step3 : Render to image

```
// Create and bind frame buffers
glViewport( 0, 0, FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT );
short draw_image_width = FRAME_WIDTH;
short draw_image_height = FRAME_HEIGHT;
unsigned int canvasFrameBuffer;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &canvasFrameBuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, canvasFrameBuffer);

unsigned int canvasRenderBuffer;
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &canvasRenderBuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, canvasRenderBuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA4, draw_image_width, draw_image_height);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, canvasRenderBuffer);

// write image out in rendering stage
glReadPixels(0, 0, draw_image_width, draw_image_height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ptr_image_out );

// unbind frame buffer
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glDeleteRenderbuffers(1, &canvasRenderBuffer);
glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &canvasFrameBuffer);
```